# Align Icon left and right from toggle-switch checkbox

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to align my two icons left and right next to my toggle switch. But I just cant find a way to make it work.

```
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <label class="form-check-label ms-3" for="lightSwitch" fill="currentColor">
        <i class="bi bi-brightness-high-fill"></i>
      </label>
      <input class="form-check-input bg-dark border border-secondary" type="checkbox" id="lightSwitch" />
      <label class="form-check-label ms-3" for="lightSwitch" fill="currentColor">
        <i class="bi bi-moon-fill"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

using `style="float: left;"` is not fixing my issue because they are overlapping themselfes.

any help? thanks!

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricks here are

1. remove the `padding:2.5em` within the `.form-switch` (*optional*)
2. remove the `margin-left: -2.5em;` within the `.form-check .form-check-input` ***(important)***
3. remove the `float:left;` within the `.form-check .form-check-input` ***(important)***

There are two approach to achieve that :

1. using `d-flex` on `.form-switch` **(Approach 1)**
2. using `float-none` on `.form-check-input` **(Approach 2)**

```css
.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.form-switch .form-check-input {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23adb5bd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23adb5bd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<h5>Approach 1</h5>
<div class="form-check form-switch d-flex ps-0">
  <i class="bi bi-brightness-high-fill me-3"></i>
  <input class="form-check-input ms-0 me-3" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <i class="bi bi-moon-fill"></i>
</div>

<h5>Approach 2</h5>
<div class="form-check form-switch ps-0">
  <i class="bi bi-brightness-high-fill me-3"></i>
  <input class="form-check-input ms-0 float-none me-3" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <i class="bi bi-moon-fill"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added bootstrap icon cdn link between `head` tags and some css code .Result is like below. If you want to do icons closer to the switch  you can remove `float-end` class

```css
.form-switch .form-check-input:checked {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.form-switch .form-check-input {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23adb5bd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
.form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23adb5bd'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
    <i class="bi bi-brightness-high-fill float-end me-3"></i>
    <i class="bi bi-moon-fill float-end me-3"></i>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: yes i did that, but is there a way to align the moon left and the sun right next to the toggle switch?

Comment: Whichever shape you want to get left, you can use float start instead of float end .

Comment: it is not working, it still remains both icons in the right